# Insert or update according to any column

Tags: mysql, bulkinsert

My problem is about bulk insert+update,

I want to insert a lot of data and update the same ones by a specific column, not by primary key at the same time. So I can't use `INSERT...ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`.

Is there a way to do that?

For example I have a "person" table and it has "name"-"phone"-"security-number" columns.
First bulk insert, I add new people, but don't want a new record that has the same name, just update its other info (phone and security-number)
Another insert operation, I add new poeple, but don't want a new record that has same phone number, just update its name and security-number.
(the example may be a little bit ridiculous,sorry for that)

Comment: 1. Since it is not a unique column, if several rows have same data in that column, will you update ALL of them? 2. Do you dynamically define which columns is that specific column or is it always the same? 3. Can there be multiple columns which you specify, or only one? 4. Can you provide a small data example?

Comment: 1.I want to add new person data,and I don't add the same name /phone number/last name/etc. this is changeable. 2. Yes the column is defined dynamically. 3.Not multiple, just one column

Answer (score 1):

It is probably not the only solution, but this is what came to my mind first. Write your trigger and create it dynamically (execute sql from your code) every time you bulk insert and after the insert you delete it, so the next time you can check on different column. Pseudo-code:

```
CREATE TRIGGER ON INSERT
BEGIN
    DECLARE t int;
    SELECT t = COUNT(1) FROM table WHERE your_defined_column = inserted.your_defined_column
    IF(t > 0)
    BEGIN
        UPDATE table SET all_columns... WHERE your_defined_column = inserted.your_defined_column
        --STOP FROM INSERTING
    END
    ELSE
        --LET IT INSERT
    END
END
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: thanks for reply, it seems good :) but does it decrease bulk insert performance? Trigger queries SELECT every insert operation.

Comment: Well, it surely will decrease its performance. However, I do not know whether it is 1% or 50% of the time. If you try this way and find out, let me know :)

Comment: Ok, I'll let you know whenever I try it, thansk again

Answer (score 0):

you can use unique key index instead of primary key. and the sql you insert will be the same.

just alter the table and add unique index on specify column.

Comment: thanks for reply, but I can't do that because the column is changeable. It could be by name, then by phone number etc. So I can't add unique keys